# C# visual studio user input for file path and file name

Tags: c#, file

I have the current code below to save a .csv file on the button click event. However, I want the user to be able to choose the file path and document name. Any suggestions on how to go about that? I could read the text from a text box for a file name, but what about the file path with out the user having to type of it in?

```
        long[][] finalResultArray = dataList.Select(a => a.ToArray()).ToArray();
        string filePath = @"C:\test\test.csv"; 
        int length = finalResultArray.GetLength(0);
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        for(int index = 0; index < length; index++)
        {
            sb.AppendLine(string.Join(",", finalResultArray[index]));
        }
        File.WriteAllText(filePath, sb.ToString());
        MessageBox.Show("Save Complete!");
```

Comment: Set a variable to a default path (if that's what you're asking), prompt the user for just the shortened filename, and always save to the same default path with the concatenated shortened filename added to the end.  Is that all you're asking to accomplish?

Comment: Maybe use [`SaveFileDialog`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.savefiledialog(v=vs.110).aspx)?

Comment: Do not use the Visual Studio tag for code that is merely _written_ in Visual Studio. The tag implies a question about Visual Studio _itself_.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use the [`SaveFileDialog`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.savefiledialog(v=vs.110).aspx) class for this:

```
SaveFileDialog saveFileDialog = new SaveFileDialog();

if(saveFileDialog.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
{
    File.WriteAllText(saveFileDialog.FileName, sb.ToString());
    MessageBox.Show("Save Complete!");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want you can also try OpenFileDialog.
System.Windows.Forms.OpenFileDialog dlg =  new System.Windows.Forms.OpenFileDialog();
dlg.ShowDialog();

Comment: No. The open file dialog is not meant for saving files. You can't specify a non-existent filename with it, and it will not warn on overwrite.