# Copy to output directory

Tags: c#

I am working on project that use other files from the outside.
Now for the tests I set up all the properties of that file in Visual Studio Code.

Like this

[image]

For turning that to dynamic, I receive from the user the full path of the file as a string.

Is it posible to change the "copy to output directory" property (of that file that I got the full path) to "copy always" in the code himself, because now I change that manualy and I want it to be dynamic.

I tried to find the answer here in stackoverflow but all the answers say that you can change it in the terminal or something.

thanks for the help :)

Comment: "Is it posible to change the "copy to output directory" property in the code" no, because that's in the csproj file, which is read before the code is even compiled. What are you trying to do?

Comment: If you get the path from the user then just load the file with the path you then have? You presumably already load that file somehow in code. Maybe show that.

Comment: Provide the file path as first parameter, and use `args[0]` ?  (or use `OpenFileDialog` (see: https://stackoverflow.com/a/51217748/724039 ))